# Wanna know how to move h6 tag over the input one

Tags: html, css, input, tags

```css
/*
    FOOTER
*/

.footer {
    background: #141618;
}

.footer .container {
    padding: 80px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.footer .logo {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    height: 60px;
}

.footer .footer-nav {
    display: flex;
}

.footer .footer-nav nav {
    margin-right: 32px;
}

.footer .footer-nav nav h6 {
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.footer .footer-nav nav ul li {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.footer .footer-nav nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 150%;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    transition: 200ms color;
}

.footer .footer-nav nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.footer .footer-nav .search {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.footer .footer-nav .search h6 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.footer .footer-nav .search form {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer .footer-nav .search input {
    height: 48px;
    width: 375px;
    background: #21252d;
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #fff;
}

.footer .footer-nav .search button {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background: #316aff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.footer .copyright {
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .05);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.footer .copyright a {
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    transition: 200ms color;
}

.footer .copyright a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.footer .copyright .text {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="logo" src="img/logo.svg" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="footer-nav">
                <nav>
                    <h6>CONTENT</h6>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Browse</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Course</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Lessons</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Podcasts</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </nav>
                <nav>
                    <h6>ABOUT</h6>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Instructors</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Stories</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Team</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Store</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="search">
                    <h6>Search for Lessons and Courses</h6>
                    <form action="">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. Javascript, React">
                        <button type="button">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="copyright">
                <a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a>
                <span class="text">
                    &copy; egghead.io
                </span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </footer>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoQ0B.png)

Hey i actually dont have that much of experience in these topics but trying to have some, i have tried to fix it but apparently i am missing something and dont know whats that any helps are appreciated sorry if there was already an answer i tried to fix it before posting it.

[hope im sharing useful parts of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3iax.png)
[and css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c27O0.png)

Comment: It's stack overflow, not imgur. Please, post the code, ideally the part your have a problem with.

Comment: actually thats cause of being my first issue in here. edited rn. and i already tried to change display settings removing or setting flex-direction: column; it didnt work either.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you shared in the image. The code you provided has heading on top of the input. If you have more CSS rules, then it might be a case, that other styles are applied and produce this horizontal-alignment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from your CSS. You have a `display: flex` in your `.footer .footer-nav .search form` selector, which makes elements flow horizontally.

You can add `flex-direction: column`, but unless you have a good reason to use flexbox in this case, you're better of by just removing it. Block elements (such as form and heading) stack on top of each other by default.

---

Note for the future: Please, at least attach the code. This way people can try out your code and see what's wrong with it. You can also set-up a "fiddle" on jsfiddle.net, so people can hop-in and tinker on the solution right in the browser.

Comment: Don't even need third-party code hosting sites when you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) in questions and answers